# Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'null'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12, ng-init

I'm getting this error, after I added a function called `ngInit` which will call the `getCountries` function in the `Service` class:

> "Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'null'"

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MessageService} from './message.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  title = 'Tour of Heroes';

  countryData = null;
  constructor(private api:MessageService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getCountries().subscribe((data)=>{
      this.countryData = data;
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because of your `countryData = null` property initialization, TypeScript infers the type of `countryData` to be `null`. Assigning anything other than `null` to this property will result in the error you're seeing.

To fix, you can:

1. Type the property as `any`:

   ```
   countryData: any = null;
   ```
2. Define a type for your data, and set the property to be either that type or `null`:

   ```
   countryData: CountryDataType | null = null;
   ```
3. Define a type for your data, set the property to be of that type, and mark it as optional (note that in this case the initial value is `undefined` instead of `null`):

   ```
   countryData?: CountryDataType;
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You have declare the return type as null or turn off strictNullChecks in your tsconfig.

Change the type null as any.

Answer (score 1):

As You've initialized countryData with null, compiler compares new value to null type - it's the same as You would initialize it with String type and try to assign a Number type.
If You need a one time solution, just use type casting.

```
this.countryData = data as any
```

instead of `this.countryData = data`

Hence:
If You wish to make this field typeCheck immune just look at @Vignesh answer.

Answer (score 0):

simple change to make it work is to change the type to any or provide a interface for country

```
countryData: any;
```

or as Robby

```
countryData:CountryDateType
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following if you dont know the response type for the api call

`countryData = <any><unknown>null;`

if you know the type of response (say it is String) you can use,

`countryData = <String><unknown>null;`